# How to make neural networks more robust(intuitive explanation)?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

Low spectral Norm ensures tight Rademacher complexity and ensures low generalization error for neural nets. Can anyone explain me this in a intuitive manner along with Rademacher view point.

[Rademacher Complexity](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Erjliao/notes/Notes_on_Rademacher_Complexity.pdf)

Comment: Could you please provide links to your source material (assume I have never heard of Rademacher complexity for example - there are dozens of data science metrics, and once you have seen a few it is reasonably quick to understand a new one)? Also, it would help someone answering if you gave more details about what you *do* already understand about low spectral norm and how it may improve generalisation errors (most regularisation does this, so it's not unexpected from a high level view). Otherwise someone answering has to make a lot of effort based on guessing what level to pitch at.

Comment: I have updated, also trying to post my view on these. Thanks for your response